# Writing JavaScript function in Django models

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to get long, lat variables from my models.py, which looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Marker(models.Model):

    latitude = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-90), MaxValueValidator(90)],
)
    longitude = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(-180), MaxValueValidator(180)],
)
```

And add fetch them to the line myLatLng in JavaScript - map.js

```
function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: "Hello World!",
  });
}
```

the sample code is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

So I would like to create a marker from my admin page and display it on the map

---

UPD:

I've included views.py now:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings


LatLng = [
{{ object.latitude }},
{{ object.longitude }}
]

def map(request):
    context = {'LatLng': LatLng}
    return render(request, "map/map.html")
```

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'latitude'

and map.js looks like this:

```
function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: {{ object.latitude }}, lng: {{ object.longitude }} };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: "Hello World!",
  });
}
```

Though it does show me an error now, see below
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnwsQ.png)

For my templates map.html, how do I include this view?
map.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>map</title>
      <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
     <script src="{% static '/map/js/map.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="{% static 'map/css/map.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBnDE9SrH7SfZw5lPOz9MDX1ScNz1W6ncE&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2"
            async
    ></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to create a view.py and template.
Reference to Class-based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/

you can pass the data to template file.

On the template the variables are looks like this:

```
{{ object.latitude }}

{{ object.longitude }}
```

So your Javascript will be like this:

```
function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: {{ object.latitude }}, lng: {{ object.longitude }} };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: "Hello World!",
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, currently I've updated my question after referncing your answer. I'm not quite sure if I have included the view.py correctly?